# Wordpress website hosted on AWS LightSail -- how and where to put business logic?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I just hossted a website (very simple) on aws lightsail for Proof of concept.
I have a wordpress server instance and also have installed a DB.
So far, if i put comment on website i can access it through the DB client (MySQL Workbench)
Now, i want to check where can i put my business logic.
Example: If a user provides a vulger comments lets say 'This website is Garbage', i want to block this comment from getting posted.

Am i missing a tool that i should install? i am very new to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom logic for WordPress is usually added to the theme `functions.php` file, or is implemented as a plugin.

For example for preventing vulgar comments in post you could install this plugin WebPurify. See
https://wordpress.org/plugins/webpurifytextreplace/

For information on how to develop your own custom plugins see https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo,
Now, what if i want to put actual business logic.. suppose i allow users to book a reservation in hotels (like AirBnB)..
If a user has already made booking for date 08/15/2020 and is trying to book again for the same date in same or different hotel.. i want to alert the user in a pop-up.. Is this something can be done by developing a plugin? I believe for this to work plugin needs to query db in real time to check if ower has already made a booking on a given date.
Please suggest

Comment: Yes you would likely need a custom plugin you build, or modify an existing plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to modify all comments... wordpress comes with some basic rules:

> You can control which comments get held for moderation on your Settings Discussion Screen page, which is located under Settings → Discussion.

Reference:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/comment-moderation/#controlling-moderation